# Make thumbnail from uploaded image without plugin

Tags: uploads, post-thumbnails

When I add image in post, I need to make some thumbnails with several sizes. Maybe someone could tell action or filter to implement this?

Comment: Did you try this http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_image_size? You can use `add_image_size` to create images of different sizes

Comment: I was using this, but it hasnt crop position.

Comment: if you have more specific needs, then update your question with more info. you don't mention crop position in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a very useful plugin: [Custom Image Size](http://austinmatzko.com/wordpress-plugins/filosofo-custom-image-sizes/)

It will automatically crop your images at your desired sizes.

Comment: Without plugin!